# Should I deadhead campanula?

Tags: flowers, dead-branch, deadheading

My campanula has started drying the flowers.
Though all of the branches are completely dried out.
Some still have few flowers.

Is this a good time to deadhead my campanula for flowering again?

[image]

Comment: which variety of Campanula is it?

Comment: @Bamboo, Campanula Adansa was written on the pot when I bought it.

Comment: @Bamboo, added an image of my flowers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh yes, I remember now, you asked another question on this plant before (Campanula poscharskyana 'Adansa').

Wait till all the flowers have faded, and cut off all flowered stems back to just leafy growth. Your plant may produce a few more flowers around September, but may not - they usually only flower the once in a year. The purpose of cutting it back is merely to keep it tidy, really. If you have somewhere outdoors you can plant it, its pretty hardy and will spread and flower again next year.